# is spring batch 4 compatible with spring boot 3?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

Currently I am trying to migrate the spring boot from 2.6.x to 3.x. I upgraded h2, hibernate and also upgraded to use Jakarata EE. I also have spring batch with version 4.x.

By default spring boot 3 uses spring batch 5.0.x. By any chance is spring batch 4.x.x compatible with spring boot 3?
As per my analysis its not but thought to check once again with experts over here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, those are incompatible. Besides the different minimum Java version requirements (Java 17 vs Java 8), the batch auto-configuration in Spring Boot 3 relies on classes that are new in Spring Batch 5 and not present in Spring Batch 4.